# How to get Container Id of Docker in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, containers

I am using [Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Custom+Build+Environment+Plugin) to build my project inside ["jpetazzo/dind"](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) docker image. After building, in console output it shows:

> Docker container 212ad049dfdf8b7180b8c9b185ddfc586b301174414c40969994f7b3e64f68bc started to host the build
>
> $ docker exec --tty 212ad049dfdf8b7180b8c9b185ddfc586b301174414c40969994f7b3e64f68bc env
>
> [workspace] $ docker exec --tty --user 122:docker 4aea29fff86ba4e50dbcc7387f4f23c55ff3661322fb430a099435e905d6eeef env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#73

Here Docker Container which got started has container id `212ad049dfdf8b7180b8c9b185ddfc586b301174414c40969994f7b3e64f68bc` .
Now further I want to execute some command on "Execute shell" part in "Build" option in Jenkins, there I want to use this Container Id. I tried using `${BUILD_CONTAINER_ID}` as mentioned in the plugin page. But that does't work.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you to use `docker run`, but you're trying to do `docker exec`. The `exec` subcommand only works on a *currently running* container.

I suppose you could do a `docker run -d` to start the container in the background, and then make sure to `docker stop` when you're done. I suspect this will leave you with some orphaned running containers when things go wrong, though.

Comment: But for `docker run` you need to pass at least 1 args, either Image Id or Container Id. Otherwise it will give this error:
> docker: "run" requires a minimum of 1 argument.
And I also tried giving Image Id, but I am getting this error:

WARNING: Error loading config file:stat /root/.docker/config.json: permission denied
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

Comment: `docker run -d jpetazzo/dind` is working outside Jenkins. But from Jenkins I am getting same permission denied error. Even my jenkins user is added in docker group.

Comment: The error sounds like you're running as `root`, when you probably ought to be `jenkins`. You're not providing enough context for me, though.

Comment: In the third command which jenkins is executing `docker exec --tty --user 122:docker` that means it is assigining userid 122 and group docker. When I am doing `whoami` it is showing `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 122` 
And also I am doing it from jenkins so I believe it will be done using `jenkins` user not `root`. And my `jenkins` user is in `docker` group.